# WP_Query : if I combine 'p' AND 'tax_query' , 'tax_query' clause is being ignored

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

If I exec this query:

```
new WP_Query(array( 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'page', 
            'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'type1',
                            ),array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'type2',
                            )
                        ) 
            )
        );
```

it returns an empty array, and it's right

but if I try to exec the same query with clause 'p', it returns the data and ignores the tax_query clause.

```
new WP_Query(array( 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'page', 
            'p' => 300 ,
            'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'type1',
                            ),array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'type2',
                            )
                        ) 
            )
        );
```

Comment: I think that you have to change `'p' => 300 ,` with `'page_id' => 300,` the `p` parameter is for post id and you are querying pages

Comment: if  I use only 'p' ( or 'page_id') query works fine. Also if I use only tax_query

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use incorrect post type. You can't use post_tag for page post type because it taxonomy only for posts.

```
new WP_Query(array( 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'type1',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'type2',
        )
    ) 
));
```

Comment: I do not agree, the first query works like a charm.